# Adding keys to express instance good practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

In the case where I would like to share some information from my index.js file to multiple endpoints in different routes, would simply sticking a custom key to the express instance (app) be fine? For example, lets say I'm using socket.io and would like multiple endpoints emitting from the instance I created, would just saying app.socketIo = io be fine? Is there a better way of doing this if this is not the case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by keys. Questions asking about best practices are usually too open ended for stack overflow. Is there something not working?

Comment: @JuanMendes Apologies. When I say key I mean the attributes in the app instance like a regular javascript object. For example Im essentially doing jsObject.color = red but with the express instance instead.

Furthermore when I say "best practice" I really just mean if I would break anything or do anything that might give me trouble in the future. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`app.set()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) and [`app.get()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get) are designed for this purpose, though some named parameters are reserved for special use.

There is also [`app.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) which a shared object that is entirely your own namespace, no conflicts at all.

While you could apply your own properties to the `app` object directly, that runs a risk of conflict with future development of Express and would generally not be recommended for that reason.  I'd suggest using `app.locals` which is conflict-free and entirely for your own use.

Values in `app.locals` values are also available to templates using the Express template interface so that's where you can set application-level variables that are available to all templates (such as an application name).